# CloudFront with S3: "X Cache Error from cloud front"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, index.html

I have cloud front and S3 for hosting frontend. I am able to load content from s3 with CloudFront. When I hit `xyz.com`, The status code is 200 and showing `Hit from cloudfront`.

Meanwhile when I hit `xyz.com/login`, I am getting 200 or 304 status, but with `Error from cloudfront`. I have added error responses for 403 and 404 and restrict to serve `index.html`.

How to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you check whether the path defined for login is correct or not ?